# How can i jump to a link without offset of a fixed navigation bar?

Tags: html

i have a fixed navigation bar on my website.
Everytime i click on an anchor link it brings me to the suggested div but with an offset which is equal to the height of the navigation bar.

How can i fix it so it jumps without that offset.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the html and code

Answer (score 1):

Show your code would be advisable. But may i suggest as a starting point make sure your navigation links are displayed as inline-block items